# Finding the subpoint on the earth's surface for the sun and

Tags: python, astronomy, skyfield

Using skyfield, the astronomical python module, I want to find the latitude and longitude for the sun and the moon subpoints, that is, the location on Earth where the body is directly overhead. I need to be able to compute them for any time of day and any day of the year. I've looked through the examples the documentation provides but I didn't find these specific calculations nor any mention of them in the text.

Is there a way of doing such a computation?

Comment: Remember to reread the posting guidelines over on ["How do I ask a good question? "](/help/how-to-ask) because your title isn't a proper summary of the problem, and your post doesn't link to the documentation you've read, nor shows any code you've already tried. (And remember: just because you use library X doesn't mean you have to _only_ use library X, what other libraries have you looked at for that information?)